# Удаление элементов списка с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

как с помощью чистого js(не jquery) удалять любой элемент списка просто кликнув на него?

```
<div id="list">
 <li class="li">1</li>
 <li class="li">2</li>
 <li class="li">3</li>
 <li class="li">4</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/**
 * @type {HTMLUListElement}
 */
let ulList = document.getElementById('list')

ulList.addEventListener('click', event => {
    /**
     * type {HTMLElement}
     */
    let el = event.target
    if (ulList === el) return;
    el.remove()
})
```

```css
ul li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
 <li class="li">1</li>
 <li class="li">2</li>
 <li class="li">3</li>
 <li class="li">4</li>
</ul>
```

литература

- [таблица совместимости](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Browser_compatibility)
- [MDN Node.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)
- learn.javascript.ru -> Добавление и удаление узлов -> [Удаление узлов](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-removechild)